# Url.Action with WebApi and Controller routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a 2 controllers, 1 of which is WebApi:

```
public class ListController : ApiController
{        
    public object Remove(string ListId, List<string> ItemIds)
    {
        //removed
    }
}

public class ListController : Controller
{        
    public object Remove(string ListId, List<string> ItemIds)
    {
        //removed
    }
}
```

My routes are registered in the Global.asax as follows:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

My WebApi route is defined as:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

When generating a url through @Url.Action("Remove", "List"), the path I get is '/list/remove'. I expected the WebApi route ('/api/list/remove') to be selected, due to the fact the WebApi routes were registered before the other routes.

How can I get @Url.Action to return the WebApi route as expected?

Comment: do you have the WebApi controller in the same project as the non-Webapi controller?

Comment: Yes. The namespaces are something.Controllers.WebAPI and something.Controllers

Comment: Heve you try to use `@Url.RouteUrl` with route name DefaultApi?

Comment: I have tried `@Url.Action("Remove", "List", new { httproute = "DefaultApi" })` and that works as expected.

Comment: Shamelessly going to add this comment as the answer, worked great for me but i initially looked over this question as it didn't have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Url.Action("Remove", "List", new { httproute = "DefaultApi" })
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that runs across this not working as expected... If your URL is generated as /List/Remove?httproute=DefaultApi

Verify that your api routes are loaded first! Order is critical.

I also added the constraints to my web route config to help exclude api routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    constraints: new { controller = @"(?!DefaultApi).*" }
);
```